# Get a list of ansible hosts for bash script

Tags: bash, ansible

**The goal:**
I want to get a list of ansible hosts (could be made out of the ansible inventory e.g.) and each element should be separated by a space. The reason for that is that I want to run a bash script which needs a list attached to it like `script.sh host_1 host_2 host_3 ...`

**The problem:**
I need to specify one host, which needs to be in front of every other host e.g. `script.sh **host_2.example.de** host_1.example.de host_3.example.de ...`

**My ansible inventory.ini example looks like:**

```ini
[manager]
host_2.example.de

[utility_nodes]
host_1.example.de host_template=Utility1 
host_2.example.de host_template=Utility2 

[master_nodes] 
host_3.example.de host_template=Master1 
host_4.example.de host_template=Master2
```

Comment: Why not use Ansible to run your `bash` script? Then your list of hostnames will be available in the `groups.all` variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do *exactly* what you're asking, you could do something like this:

```
$ hosts=$(ansible-inventory -i hosts --list  |
  jq  -r '[values[]|.hosts|select(.)[]]|unique[]')
$ echo $hosts
host_1.example.de host_2.example.de host_3.example.de host_4.example.de
```

This uses `ansible-inventory` to produce a JSON dump of your inventory, and then `jq` to query that for a list of hosts.

But that seems like a terrible idea.

Since you're already using Ansible, why not just use Ansible to run your script? Use a playbook like this:

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - name: Run script
      command: ./script.sh {{ groups.all|join(' ') }}
```

To ensure that `host_2` is the first host, you could write:

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  become: true
  tasks:
    - name: Run script
      command: ./script.sh {{ groups.manager|join(' ') }} {{ groups.all|reject("in", groups.manager)|join(' ') }}
      register: res

    - debug:
        var: res.stdout
```

This will ensure that members of the `manager` group are always at the front of the list of host.s

Comment: Thanks, tbh I'm quiet new to ansible but that variable seems to lead in the right direction.  Is it also possible to get a specific host in front like I mentioned in my question. So that it would start with host_2.example.de and then the rest of the hosts?